# Send data and instructions to nodes in distributed application

Tags: hadoop, serialization, mapreduce, distributed-computing

I am looking to make a very simple `MapReduce` implementation.

I don't really need a truly distributed system where the fact that they are different machines is abstracted out. This is a personal project and that is far too complex. I just want worker nodes to be able to register with the head node. Then I want to be able to tell the head node to run a map or reduce on a data set with a given function. The master node can then offload pieces of the work to worker nodes.

My question is: 
**How should I send the actual function to the worker nodes so they know what do do with the data they have?**

So say as a client i want to do the following (*in python as an example*):

`[1, 2, 3, 4].map(lambda x: x * 2)`

(but the function and data set could be a lot more complex).

How should I communicate the function to the nodes without creating too much overhead?

My best idea is to serialize the function as string and then deserialize on the other end but this seems slow. Another thought is to compile it before sending but this leads to a host of complexity.

I have tried to look into how hadoop works to see if I could make a simplified version but it obviously their solution is far more involved.

Comment: Look into [remote procedure calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) such as JSON-RPC.

Comment: @BeauBarker My main hurdle is that I want a client to be able to define a function and then send that function to the server to execute. Before the client makes the call the server has no knowledge of the function definition.

So I would need to send the actual definition of the function, not just its name. This doesn't seem possible with JSON-RPC (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Ok, is ssh out of the question?

Comment: @BeauBarker It's not necessarily out of the question but if there's a way i can handle this without ssh I would perfer that. Managing keypairs for any possible worker node seems unreasonable. Plus it's slow and adds overhead. At that point I might as well send a source file over http. Which I guess is an option, albeit not perfect.